# Is there a way around this gem dependency issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to use both the twitter gem and the pingdom-client gem in a small api health/status site I need to build.

When I try to bundle install the pingdom-client gem, I get the following error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    pingdom-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.5.6) ruby

    twitter (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.8.4)
```

What are my options for resolving this issue? Or do I need to abandon the use of one of these gems?

Comment: Do you have both versions of the faraday gem installed?

Comment: make pingdom-client work with faraday 0.8+ (it may or may not need any real code change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a newer version of `pingdom-client` available with a better dependency, so you can try creating one on your own.

1. Uninstall all versions of `faraday` with `gem uninstall faraday`
2. Fork [`pingdom-client`](https://github.com/mtodd/pingdom-client).
3. Change it's dependency on `faraday` to `(~> 0.8.4)` it it's [`pingdom-client.gemspec`](https://github.com/mtodd/pingdom-client/blob/master/pingdom-client.gemspec)
4. Change your `Gemfile` line to

   ```
    gem 'pingdom-client', git: 'url/to/your/git/fork.git'
   ```
5. Run `bundle`

Check your application to see if all is well with `pingdom-client` running the newer version of `faraday`

Comment: Thanks great answer. Solved my answer and taught me something in the process. When I take over in a bane type capacity you shall live!

Comment: Yeah the pingdom gem didn't actually work in the end so just ended up calling the api with HTTParty which was fine